# Extracting data from csv file to put on UI table view

Tags: swift, xcode, csv, url

I was wondering if I could ask a question regarding csv/http posting. I want my data to update within my app after I pull the data from my github csv file, but when I do, it doesn't update within the app but just prints the numbers. What's wrong with my code? Thanks!

class NewStats: UITableViewController {

```
var didTapMenuType: ((NewMenu) -> Void)?

var Num2:String = "2"

@IBOutlet weak var MultnomahText: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var MultnomahView: UIProgressView!



override func viewDidLoad() {



                   let url = URL(string: "SampleUrl.csv")!

                   let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in

                   guard let data = data else { return }

                   let str = (String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)

                   let fullNameArr = str.components(separatedBy: ",")

                   let Num1    = fullNameArr[0]

                   self.Num2 = fullNameArr[1]

                   let Num3   = fullNameArr[2]

                   let Num4 = fullNameArr[3]

                   let Num5    = fullNameArr[4]

                   let Num6 = fullNameArr[5]

                   let Num7    = fullNameArr[6]

                   let Num8 = fullNameArr[7]

                   let Num9    = fullNameArr[8]

                   let Num10 = fullNameArr[9]



                   print(Num1);

                   print(self.Num2);

                   print(Num3);

                   print(Num4);

                   print(Num5);

                   print(Num6);

                   print(Num7);

                   print(Num8);

                   print(Num9);

                   print(Num10);







}

task.resume()

super.viewDidLoad()



DispatchQueue.main.async {

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}



print(self.Num2);



self.MultnomahText.text = "Multnomah:" + self.Num2

self.MultnomahView.setProgress(0.5, animated: true)



}
```

Comment: Suggestion: try to format your code before posting. It makes it a bit easier to read ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After the print(Num10)

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.MultnomahText.text = "Multnomah:" + self.Num2
                       self.MultnomahView.setProgress(0.5, animated: true)
                       self.tableView.reloadData()
                       }
```

Hopefully this helps!